# Создание подпапки в папке files

Tags: java, android, файлы

Создаю приложение на Android и хочу чтобы в папке files на телефоне пользователя всегда при запуске приложения была папка files (типо проверка существует ли такая папка и если нет то создать ее в директории с data/com.appname.appname). 
А потом определенные файлы (допустим картинки) сохранять туда. 
Как это реализовать?

Дело в том что проверку существования папки я осуществил, но при попытке создать файл в папке `/files/quizes/FileName.txt` выходит ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
File /quizes/FileName.txt contains a path separator
```

Вот кусок кода отвечающий за создание файла:

```
String quizfileDir = "/quizes/" + quizfileName;

FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(quizfileDir, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: что именно у вас не получается? что пробовали? пока не понятно в чем именно у вас проблема

Comment: Вот как описано в вопросе, так и реализовать

Comment: у вас путь к папке какой вы используете в коде?

Comment: Зачем это вам? Файлы будут редактироваться во время выполнения или загружаться извне? Если нет - используйте ассеты/ресурсы (файлы запакованные в приложение) без бессмысленного копирования в память устройства.

Comment: Файлы можно будет скидывать и получать от пользователей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openFileOutput()` не поддерживает подпапки. Если хотите свободную иерархию - используйте классы `File` и `FileOutputStream`, а путь к папке `files` получайте методом `getFilesDir()`:

```java
File quizesDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "quizes");
if (!quizesDir.exists()) { // если папка не существует
    quizesDir.mkdirs(); // создаём её
    
    // и записываем файл(ы)
    File quizfile = new File(quizesDir, quizfileName);
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(quizfile)) {
        ...
    }
}
```